# nested dynamic routing in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, url-routing

i have the following folder structure in next.js pages folder:

```
pages/folder1/folder2/[id]/index.js
pages/folder1/folder2/[id]/folder3/[id]/index.js
```

The first one is working ok, however on the second link i get error : 404 page not found.

Is this an error in my code or I missed something important in the documentation about nesting dynamic routes?

Comment: From documentation your code should be working. Have you double checked that the [id] folders in the second link acuatlly exist?

Comment: yeah... strange thing is that it works this way:
pages/folder1/folder2/[id]/folder3/[slug]/index.js
I will use it as a workaround.

Comment: When using multiple dynamic route segments, each dynamic segment needs to have a unique name so that you can access them correctly in the `query` object. Hence why renaming the second `[id]` works.

Comment: thanks a lot julio. i think you are correct here.

Comment: I've same issue. My project structure look like - pages/categories/[id]/index.jsx and pages/categories/[id]/articleIs/[articlesId].jsx ..can anyone help me?